# Default value for foreign key columns

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, default-value

I am working on a multi-tenant web application with PHP/MySQL. And I have come up to a matter of general convention regarding the foreign keys and default values.

I have a **MailTemplate** table that i store templates used in mails sent for various actions in the application. The table columns are as follows:

```
MailTemplate
  id (PK)
  company_id (FK)
  name
  subject
  body
```

The company_id column references to **Company** table. Basically companies can create different templates for their actions. But I also want to have a predefined templates for each action, in case the company does not choose the customize a personal template.

I believe I am supposed to store these default templates in this table. But the question is, am I to keep the *company_id* column for default templates as *NULL*, or shall I just create a dummy row in **Company** table and reference the id of that row in the **MailTemplate** table?

I have checked around, but everyone seems to have done in a different way. I am wondering what the general convention for this case is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NULL is cleaner.  Dummy rows were necessary in the olden days when data storage could not easily handle the NULL condition.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc, but the queries do not seem to use the index when i query as 'where company_id IS NULL'. Isn't this a disadvantage?

Comment: It depends on how many times you run that query, and it depends on how many NULL foreign key values you have.  If 50% or more of your foreign keys are null, you might as well be doing a table scan anyway.  If 10% or less of your foreign keys are null, then yes, a dummy record would be faster.  In between, it depends on which database we're talking about.